# WrapPanel inside ListBox in UWP

Tags: xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I am looking to add `WrapPanel` inside my `ListBox` so that it's item wrap both vertically and horizentally. I was able to achieve this in Windows Phone 8 Sliverlight with Microsoft toolkit with below code;

Windows Phone 8

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListSection" ItemsSource="{Binding Section}" > 
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ></toolkit:WrapPanel>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Margin="20">
   <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="80" Height="80"></Image>
   <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextBlockBase}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Foreground="Black"
                Text="{Binding Header}"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
 </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I understand that Microsoft toolkit it not available in UWP, is there any possibility I could achieve such behavior in UWP?

UWP not working

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Section}">
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></StackPanel>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
          <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="80" Height="80"></Image>
          <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Foreground="Black"
                      Text="{Binding Header}"
                      FontWeight="Bold"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
       </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain "not working" a little more fully. Exactly what isn't working?

Comment: Thank you, @chrisF the items of the listbox shown all horizentally, it's not wrapped GraceF sorry it's not duplicate ( I know the usage VariableSizedWrapGrid)

Comment: there is a StackPanel as ItemsPanel in your sample code. Set ItemsPanelTemplate to ItemsWrapGrid

Answer (score 1):

You must use ListView and ItemsWrapGrid as ItemsPanel

you can check the MSDN docs here with examples

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.aspx

This example is for GridView but is the same for ListView

```
<GridView>
<GridView.ItemsPanel> 
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>  
    </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

you can use the property Orientation to set your items vertically or horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

There is a port of the Toolkit's WrapPanel for UWP in the project [WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit).

You can get it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.uwp).

Then in your `Page` add this prefix:

```
xmlns:toolkit="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
```

Now you can use `<toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ></toolkit:WrapPanel>` as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

@ARH you need to create a custom Panel  class which inherits panel class and override MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride methods.check out following links for reference. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228347.aspx
http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2015/02/20/Creating-a-WrapPanel-for-your-Windows-Runtime-apps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `WrapPanel` is available from the [Microsoft UWP Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel).

Here's some sample code (using `v5.0.0`):

```
...

xmlns:toolkit="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

...

<ListView
    Name="WrapPanelContainer" 
    Width="310" Height="200"
    Margin="0,40,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Background="LightBlue"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <toolkit:WrapPanel VerticalSpacing="10" HorizontalSpacing="10" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="200"  Height="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="50"  Height="50"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Width="150"  Height="50"/>
</ListView>
```

NOTE: The `ListItemView` style here removes superfluous padding, allowing the `WrapPanel` spacing properties to be the control points for layout.